# Force10 layer 3 switches

Tags: cisco, routing, switch, juniper, dell

We've been running Cisco and dell layer 3 switches. The former are expensive and reliable, the latter a lot cheaper and fraught with issues. Anyone has positive experience with the core Force10 switches (and edge switches as well)?

Comment: What kind of issues have you had with the Dell switches? I've been running a PC6024 for about 3 years with no problems.

Comment: Seconded about Dell switch reliability. We have three stacks of 6x PowerConnect 6248P (18 total) for our client access layer. They've all been rock solid for three years. The web-based configuration GUI is very clunky, but otherwise they just plain work. Stacking, failover, multi-chassis link aggregation, etc. all "just work."

Comment: Load on the dell switches would rise and stay pinned without any good explanation. It's been over 2 years so I don't have the details handy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force10 makes excellent switches, especially at higher throughput (10 gigabit gear) and predominantly figure in the high performance computing space. You should look carefully at what protocols you are expecting to run though if there is anything esoteric. The other vendors Cisco in particular but also Juniper have much more complete protocol support.

Answer (score 1):

Not personally, although friends in the supercomputing realm quite like them.

I'm a fan of the Juniper EX4200 switches, although unless you have a good vendor they're not that much cheaper then Cisco.

HP could be another option for simple stuff.